# changing jira field types via direct db edit

Tags: jira

I have to change one JIRA customfield type without recreating it (to keep field id is critical). I've done similar things before - switched single select to multiselect or other select-type, but now I have somewhat more mutually distinctive types. Especially - database value plugin customfield and standard select list.

as it seems to me to perform the swith from databasevalue to selectlist type I should:

0. stop the application
1. change customfieldtypekey and customfieldsearcherkey in 'customfield' table
2. delete the row with default value for appropriate config from 'genericconfiguration' table
3. create options trough ui and put its id's to 'customfieldvalue' table instead of old one ids
   of databasevalues plugin table entities.
4. delete databasevalue_field_key.properties from classes folder

should I swith text values to id's at the 'changeitem' table to the new ones as well? Am I missing something other?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that. Plus a full reindex. I wouldn't change the history in changeitem since that data is just a snapshot of when each change was made

But really there's a deeper problem if you can't change the custom field id. I'd look into solving that one first

Comment: what deeper problem are you referring to? I have not faced any when swithing from multi to single select with keeping field id

Comment: Assuming that a field id will stay constant may not be true in the long run, I've found

Comment: do you mean that Jira itself can spontaneously change field id? Neither me nor collegues of mine have seen that.
could be the field key spontaneously changed too?

Comment: No it won't but it's not a good idea to hard code a custom field id into code, exactly because you may want to change the type but not by updating the DB